# IBM Blockchain platform specifications

Tags: blockchain

So I saw an ad for IBM's blockchain platform, specifically the campaign they have to "turn plastic into money" by way of exchanging recyclable materials for digital tokens.

I was just wondering if anyone knows the specifications of their blockchain. I assume with it being IBM that it's all very centralized and hush-hush, though if you're willing to go the extra mile, or already have an IBM account you can download a technical brief of their platform. Does anyone have this, or know what their consensus mechanism(s) is/are or basically any information pertaining to the technical specifications of the platform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure it's not referring to hyperledger? https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/hyperledger. Also https://github.com/hyperledger

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps. It did say "Powered by IBM Blockchain" .. I'll try to look into that specific application a bit more, the "turn recyclables into money" digital token application, and see if it is in fact just hyperledger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First IBM Blockchain is IBM's branded version of it's Hyperledger Fabric blockchain software (which is Apache 2-licensed open source under the Linux Foundation). They are basically the same, with the exception of add-on services and configuration.

Unlike Bitcoin, Hyperledger Fabric is an enterprise blockchain intended for private use (such as consortiums).

The "plastics into money" is just marketing--it's an example of using blockchain in a "proof of concept" application.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the info!
I wasn't sure if it was just a different application of Hyperledger or if it was a different project all together.